# Only show the complete form at the end of the quiz

Tags: theming, quiz

In the Quiz module, After each question that the user answers, it shows a page that have some information (such as: right or wrong, question, answers, etc.).

And in the last of quiz it shows a complete form too.

I want to change this, so that the form is shown just at the end and not after each question. Is there a template I should change or some other way I can change the normal module behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about the Quiz module to say for sure but have you checked out the theme functions available for Quiz?

There is a theme function called `theme_quiz_take_summary()`.
It has a form that it adds if the quiz is set to display_feedback. Maybe it's a setting for the quiz somewhere?

```
// Get the feedback for all questions. These are included here to provide maximum flexibility for themers
if ($quiz->display_feedback) {
  $form = drupal_get_form('quiz_report_form', $questions);
  $output .= drupal_render($form);
}
```

If you want to have your own version of that theme function you should place the whole function in your theme and replace theme_quiz_take_summary() with NAMEOFYOURTHEME_quiz_take_summary().